Is it possible to automatically set the publication time to 8am on new posts?
This might be kind of funky to pull off, but does anyone have any ideas on how I could automatically set the time to 8am on any newly created post drafts? In both the Classic Editor and the Block Editor?
Edit: The Block Editor uses React; this creates some issues. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-set-the-time-on-a-new-post-to-8am-using-an-action-hook/
I write a week's worth of scheduled posts at a time, and I change the time to 8am on each so that they are published early and the "new post" emails go out early. It will save a few steps if each time I create a new post, the time is set to 8am. I don't want to set the date, only the time.
I suppose I need to hook into the new post function and use wp_insert_post_data. Then I can then set the date in the future for a scheduled publication.
I know there are 4 date/time fields: post_date, post_modified, and their GMT variants. Date/time values are in this format: 2024-10-01 12:00:00
I'd also like to be sure that the function to change the time only runs once, on new post creation, so that the user can change the time, if needed, in a future post revision.

note that there isn't really a publish time when the post is a draft as it isn't published. Why do you want to set the publish time to 8am? There may be other solutions to your problem if you provide some context ( and it might narrow down others that wouldn't be appropriate )

Thanks! I write a week's worth of scheduled posts at a time, and I change the time to 8am on each so that they are published early and the "new post" emails go out early. It will save a few steps if each time I create a new post, the time is set to 8am. And of course I need to set the day manually for each.

Use a different hook instead, it will work on both create & update events:
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_time_to_eight_am', 999, 2 );

function set_time_to_eight_am( $post_id, $post ){    
 remove_action( 'save_post', 'set_time_to_eight_am', 999 );
    
 $post->post_date = explode(' ', $post->post_date)[0] . ' 08:00:00';
 wp_update_post( $post );

 add_action( 'save_post', 'set_time_to_eight_am', 999, 2 );
}

sorry for the formatting, hard to write code in this wiki style textarea

Thanks! I'll try this out. is it possible to have it run only on create and not run on update?

Sorry, but this simply doesn't work, either for a new post or a draft updated.

@BlueDogRanch you need it on Update as well, because the post is created the moment you start editing it, not when you publish it. when you publish it, its an update event which changes the post_status. as for the issue, cant test it atm.

you can automate this hour selection with the following code. take into account that this code also affect the date of a post created trough the API.
add_filter("wp_insert_post_data", function ($data, $postarr, $unsanitized_postarr, $update) {
    
    
    if (    !$update
        &&  ("post" === $data["post_type"])
        &&  ("auto-draft" === $data["post_status"])
    ) {
        
        $date = current_datetime()
            ->modify("tomorrow 08:00:00")
            ->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        ;
        
        $data["post_date"] = $date;
        
    }
    
    
    return $data;
    
}, 10, 4);

what is also possible to do is to retrieve the last draft that you saved and then set the next draft date to the next day instead of tomorrow.

I think this is almost the answer but it does a bit more than set it to 8am, it sets it to always be tomorrow, it should only modify the hours and minutes.

Yes, all I want to do is set the time. If a new post is started after 8am, it should still stay the current day.

This works some of the time, but sometimes it appears to break the editor and make the save button unclickable.

It could be creating a loop; is there a way to make it run once?

I don't had a loop with my test. maybe edit your question to show the exact code you try.

I tried your exact code.

this code alone doesn't make a loop. then you probably have other plugin or theme which interfere. then you need to debug on your side to find when there is the problem, it's difficult to us to find where is the problem.

@BlueDogRanch if an infinite loop was somehow executing within JavaScript, the tab would completely hang making the entire interface unresponsive, and likely eventually completely crash (at least, short of it occurring in a web worker). If your tab isn't crashing, you might find an error and a stack trace in your browser's JavaScript console.

UPDATE:
You need to change data to the new published post, so you need to know the post_id before change some of its metadata.
Using the filter 'wp_insert_post_data' could not work in some conditions, due to plugin conflicts or other environment behaviour.
The code below should work as expected. Please try it.
function set_default_post_time_to_8am_after_publish( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // Check if the post is new (not updated) and is of type "draft" or "auto-draft"
    if ( $update || $post->post_status !== 'draft' ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the post has already been processed
    if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_set_8am_time', true ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Set the post date to 8:00 AM
    $current_date = substr( $post->post_date, 0, 10 ); // Get only the date (YYYY-MM-DD)
    $new_post_date = $current_date . ' 08:00:00';
    $new_post_date_gmt = get_gmt_from_date( $new_post_date ); // Adjust GMT time

    // Update the values in the database
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->posts,
        array(
            'post_date' => $new_post_date,
            'post_date_gmt' => $new_post_date_gmt,
        ),
        array( 'ID' => $post_id )
    );

    // Add a meta field to indicate that the post has been processed
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_set_8am_time', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_after_insert_post', 'set_default_post_time_to_8am_after_publish', 10, 3 );


Thanks! But I tried this on two different Wordpress installs, and  with the Classic and the Block editor, and nothing happens. No errors in debug. The Block editor may be part of the problem https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-set-the-time-on-a-new-post-to-8am-using-an-action-hook/

Hi @BlueDogRanch take a look to the code, I changed it from the previous version. It should do what you need.

Doesn't work; see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-set-the-time-on-a-new-post-to-8am-using-an-action-hook/
